# jQuery Side Panel with back button compatibility

Tags: jquery, ajax, css

I'm trying to create a portfolio site that when someone clicks on one of my projects, a side panel slides in from the right.  I'd like the panel to be 100% width and height of the viewport. The user will also have the option to click a link or the browser back button to animate the panel back. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<style>
#side-panel {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 1s all;
  -webkit-transition: 1s all; }
  #side-panel:target {
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 1; }

</style>
<div id="side-panel">

    <div class="content">
        <a href="#" class="close">Close</a>
    </div>
</div>

<ul class="projects">
    <li><a href="#side-panel">Project 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#side-panel">Project 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#side-panel">Project 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Is this what you're looking for? The side panel shows using :target (when the link changes to #side-panel)

Comment: This works perfectly! Well done using only CSS3 Transitions.  Never thought about using the pseudo class `target`. Again, well done!